# How to pass by reference or emulate it

Tags: javascript, reference

I have two IFFE:

```
var Helper = (function () {
    return {
        number: null,
        init: function (num) {
            number = num;
        }
    }
})();

var Helper2 = (function () {
    return {
        options: {
            number: [],
        },
        init: function(num){
            this.options.number = num;
        },
        getData: function () {
            return this.options.number;
        }
  }
})();


Helper2.init(Helper.number);
console.log(Helper2.getData());
Helper.init(5);
console.log(Helper2.getData());
```

What I want is

```
Helper2.init(Helper.number);
console.log(Helper2.getData()); // null
Helper.init(5);
console.log(Helper2.getData()); // 5
```

what I get is

```
Helper2.init(Helper.number);
console.log(Helper2.getData()); // null
Helper.init(5);
console.log(Helper2.getData()); // null
```

What techniques can be done to have it pass by reference, if it can?

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/gomakubeka/1/edit?js,console

Edit: Before tons of people start incorporating different ways to have `Helper2 depend on Helper`, the actual implementation of `Helper` is unknown and could have 100's of ways they implement the number, so Helper2 needs the memory address.

Edit 2: I suppose the path I was hoping to get some start on was knowing that arrays/objects do get passed by reference, how can I wrap this primitive type in such a way that I can use by reference

Comment: What is concrete about the code that you have?  When you say that there are 100s of ways `Helper` can implement the number, does that mean the the current schema is that `Helper` will always have an attribute right on the root of the object that is of `Number` type?

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate Helper directly into Helper2 ?

Comment: @zero298 Yes.  It may be in a variable called  `.randomNumber`  in someone elses implementation of `Helper`

@Jean-BaptisteYunès  I would need an interface then that has a common way to get the value I want, but there is no interface (and there isnt a strict way to do it AFIK in js).

Answer (score 1):

Passing by reference in JavaScript can only happen to objects.
The only thing you can pass by value in JavaScript are primitive data types.

If on your first object you changed the "number:null" to be nested within an options object like it is in your second object then you can pass a reference of that object to the other object. The trick is if your needing pass by reference to use objects and not primitive data types. Instead nest the primitive data types inside objects and use the objects.

I altered you code a little bit but I think this works for what you were trying to achieve.

```js
var Helper = function (num) { 
    return {
        options: {
            number: num
        },
        update: function (options) {
            this.options = options;
        }
    }
};

var Helper2 = function (num) {
    return {
        options: {
            number: num,
        },
        update: function(options){
            this.options = options;
        },
        getData: function () {
            return this.options.number;
        }
  }
};

var tempHelp = new Helper();
var tempHelp2 = new Helper2();
tempHelp2.update(tempHelp.options);
tempHelp.options.number = 5;
console.log(tempHelp2.getData());
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Great answer, took the liberty to put your answer in a code snippet so people can see the result.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks  for putting it in a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why doesn't it work:

`helper` is a self activating function that returns an object. When `init` is called upon it sets an number to the `Helper` object.

Then in `Helper2` you pass an integer (`Helper.number`) to `init` setting the object to null. So you're not passing the reference to `Helper.number`. Only the value set to it.

You need to pass the whole object to it and read it out.

An example:

```js
var Helper = (function () {
    return {
        number: null,
        init: function (num) {
            this.number = num; //add this
        }
    }
})();

var Helper2 = (function () {
    return {
        options: {
            number: [],
        },
        init: function(obj){
            
            this.options = obj; //save a reference to the helper obj.
        },
        getData: function () {
            if (this.options.number)
            {
                return this.options.number;
            }
        }
  }
})();


Helper2.init(Helper);  //store the helper object
console.log(Helper2.getData());
Helper.init(5);
console.log(Helper2.getData());
```

Comment: This relies on a certain interface that Helper has to conform to, in order for Helper2 to know what the variable is named.  For example its possible that Helper.thisisthenumber  is where the number I want is stored. Unfortunately interfaces aren't something in javascript so I have no contract between the two objects

Comment: You are right. There are solutions to that. If you want something to be generic it requires more lines of code. Look into prototype inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to get exactly what you want.  However, in one of your comments you said:

> Unfortunately interfaces aren't something in javascript

That isn't exactly true.  Yes, there's no strong typing and users of your code are free to disregard your suggestions entirely if you say that a function needs a specific type of object.

But, you can still create an interface of sorts that you want users to extend from in order to play nice with your own code.  For example, you can tell users that they must `extend` from the `Valuable` class with provides a mechanism to access a `value` computed property which will be a `Reference` instance that can encapsulate a primitive (solving the problem of not being able to pass primitive by reference).

Since this uses computed properties, this also has the benefit of leveraging the `.value` notation.  The thing is that the `.value` will be a `Reference` instead of the actual value.

```js
// Intermediary class that can be passed around and hold primitives
class Reference {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
  }
}

// Interface that dictates "value"
class Valuable {
  constructor() {
    this._value = new Reference();
  }
  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(v) {
    this._value.val = v;
  }
}

// "Concrete" class that implements the Valuable interface
class ValuableHelper extends Valuable {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

// Class that will deal with a ValuableHelper
class Helper {
  constructor(n) {
    this.options = {
      number: n
    }
  }
  getData() {
    return this.options.number;
  }
  setData(n) {
    this.options.number = n;
  }
}

// Create our instances
const vh = new ValuableHelper(),
  hh = new Helper(vh.value);

// Do our stuff
console.log(hh.getData().val);
vh.value = 5;
console.log(hh.getData().val);
hh.setData(vh.value);
vh.value = 5;
```

Comment: I am limited to ES5 but Ill look into what is possible